# query in Wikidata: how to retrieve the labels for instances

Tags: sparql, wikidata, rdfs

I'm trying to get info e.g. for Belgium for aerodromes or stations with having the label of all instances for each item (e.g. Brussels South Charleroi Airpor can be an airport, business, etc..)
I've written two separate queries but struggling to join them

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?poi ?itemLabel_nl ?itemLabel_fr ?itemLabel_en ?itemLabel_wa ?itemLabel_vls
WHERE {
  ?poi p:P17 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P17/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q31.
      {
        ?poi p:P31 ?statement1.
        ?statement1 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q62447.
      }
      UNION
      {
        ?poi p:P31 ?statement2.
        ?statement2 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q12819564.
      }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_nl filter (lang(?itemLabel_nl) = "nl") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_fr filter (lang(?itemLabel_fr) = "fr") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_en filter (lang(?itemLabel_en) = "en") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_wa filter (lang(?itemLabel_wa) = "wa") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_vls filter (lang(?itemLabel_vls) = "vls") . }
}
```

and the second part to get labels for the exact item (e.g. Brussels South Charleroi Airpor):

```
    SELECT ?instance ?instanceLabel
WHERE
{
     wd:Q1431012 p:P31 ?statement.
     ?statement ps:P31 ?instance.
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?instanceLabel
```

any thought here? :)

Comment: I don't get your question - the first one is returning stations and airports in Belgium with its labels in different languages, the second returns the English label of the types for a particular Wikidata entity, using "instances" as variable name here is confusing - the entity itself is the instance related to the Wikidata types via `wdt:P31` property

Comment: if your reformulate the goal of the second query to get the labels of the direct types of each entity, it makes more sense to me. Also, the first property path has a superflous `wdt:P279*` which doesn't make sence as nothing will be a subclass of Belgium

Comment: part 1: `SELECT DISTINCT ?poi ?typeLabel ?itemLabel_nl ?itemLabel_fr ?itemLabel_en ?itemLabel_wa ?itemLabel_vls
WHERE {
  ?poi (p:P17/ps:P17) wd:Q31.
      {
        ?poi p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q62447.
      }
      UNION
      {
        ?poi p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q12819564.
      }
`

Comment: part 2: `?poi p:P31/ps:P31 ?type
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_nl filter (lang(?itemLabel_nl) = "nl") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_fr filter (lang(?itemLabel_fr) = "fr") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_en filter (lang(?itemLabel_en) = "en") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_wa filter (lang(?itemLabel_wa) = "wa") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?poi rdfs:label ?itemLabel_vls filter (lang(?itemLabel_vls) = "vls") . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { ?type rdfs:label ?typeLabel . bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: the query performs exactly as I was trying to explain! You got me well :) thanks a lot especially for the explanation! The question can be considered as closed